# Logback RollingFileAppender doesn't work

Tags: logging, slf4j, logback

I'm struggling with a very weird issue on logback, and I need some help.

I already take a lot of time on this site and on many others, but none of the proposed solutions worked for me.

So, my problem is the following : I have an slf4j/logback configuration that work very well on my application, but the RollingFileAppender doesn't work at all !
The configuration of one of my appender looks like :

```
<appender name="telemisRollingFileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_HOME}/msg.log</file>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/msg.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d %-5level %logger{35} - %class{150}.%method %line - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Even with the maxFileSize = 5MB tag, my log can weight more than 2GB and no rolling is done.
I tried a lot of thing, change the pattern, change the size, use another trigger,... nothing worked.

I use logback 1.1.3 and slf4j 1.7.12.

I'm a little desperate... Any idea ?

Thanks a  lot,

Seb

Comment: Since you're already using slf4j, maybe you could consider switching to log4j2?

Comment: No, we take the decision to use logback and I have to stick with it. Moreover, logback work extremely well, except this rollingpolicy problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and noticed that roll-over doesn't work in case of the log file cannot be deleted or renamed. This happens if there's another application accessing the file. You can use tools like ProcessExplorer to check which processes have open file handles or try to rename the file manually.